# Problems with gzip compression with jersey

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey, compression, jax-rs

I want to enable compression features on jersey. I have a webservice that must return a list of events on json format.
For exemple :

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "pageCount": 1,
  "list": [
    {
      "pk": 1,
      "state": "ACTIVE",
      "locationType": "ADDRESS",
      "title": "titre",
      "description": "hello",
      "country": "osef",
      "city": "osef",
      "address": "osef",
      "inAgendaCount": 0,
      "dateBeginning": 1498734400758
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I enable gzip compression, the response is like this :

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "pageCount": 1,
  "list": [
    {
    }
  ]
}
```

All the events in the list are cut off.
Here is my webservice :

```
@Component
@Path("/")
public class EventSearchWebService {

    @Autowired
    private EventSearchController controller;

    @GET
    @Path("/event/search")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @JsonView(SmallView.class)
    public Response search(@QueryParam("keywords") String keywords, @DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("page") Long page) {

        if (keywords != null && !keywords.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return Response.status(200).entity(controller.search(keywords, page)).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(200).entity(controller.search(page)).build();
        }
    }
}
```

My resourceConfig with compression :

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        // Compression
        register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);
        EncodingFilter.enableFor(this, GZipEncoder.class);

        register(EventSearchWebService.class);

        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(ValidationFeature.class);
        register(ValidationExceptionMapper.class);
        register(CrossDomainContainerResponseFilter.class);

        registerClasses(AccessDeniedExceptionMapper.class,
                GeneralUserExceptionMapper.class,
                NoResultExceptionMapper.class,
                UnknowExceptionMapper.class,
                ValidationExceptionMapper.class);
    }
}
```

And my pageableList class :

```
public class PageableList<E> {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonView(value = {SmallView.class, FullView.class})
    private long page;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonView(value = {SmallView.class, FullView.class})
    private long pageCount;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonView(value = {SmallView.class, FullView.class})
    private List<E> list;

    public PageableList() {
        super();
    }

    public PageableList(List<E> list) {
        super();
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

There is no errors in the logs. Is there someone that have a clue of what's happening ?

Thank you

EDIT : after further investigations, I found out that if I send directly my list of events without PageableList, I have the error :

```
Can not resolve PropertyFilter with id 'org.vagrant.server.entity.EventEntity'; no FilterProvider configured (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the ResourceConfig.
This line :

```
register(EntityFilteringFeature.class);
```

is useless and cause the bug.